# Нету функции изменяющий фон страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, я сейчас изучаю JS и решил по приколу сделать код, который вычисляет 1000-7 и так до -1. Когда переменная доходит до -1, я хочу, чтобы изменился фон страницы.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    var block = document.getElementById('block');
    var ghoul = 1000;
    function ya_ghoul(){
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/maxresdefault.jpg')";
    }
    while(ghoul>0){
    console.log(ghoul);
    ghoul = ghoul - 7;}
    while(ghoul<0){
        ya_ghoul();
    }
</script></head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ииииииииииииии?

Comment: Оно не изменяеться в во втором цикле

Comment: А зачем тут второй цикл?

Comment: Действительно. Спасибо, за то что указали на ненужный фрагмент кода

Comment: вместо него надо будет написать If ...

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Максимально красивое и полное решение, прошу оцените мой ответ.

```
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        *{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        body{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #block{
            color: white;
            background-color: black;
            text-align:center;
            font-size: 72px;
            padding-top: 45vh;
            width: inherit;
            height: inherit;
        }
        img{
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 100%;
            width: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="block"></div>
    <script>
        function sleep(delay){ //Нужна для того чтобы числа не прошли от 1000 до 1 мнгновенно
            return new Promise(resolve=>{
                setTimeout(resolve,delay);
            })
        }
        async function ya_ghoul(){
            let block = document.getElementById('block');
            let ghoul = 1000;
            while(ghoul > 0){
                await sleep(20); //0,1 от секунды
                block.innerHTML = String(ghoul) + " - 7";
                ghoul=ghoul-7;
            }
            block.style = "padding: 0;"
            block.innerHTML = "<img src='https://gameinside.ua/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/a5a8d5c3af00d6019a7120ab8ddc2e9c.jpg'/>";
        }
        ya_ghoul();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]